# Switching to live mode - PayPal JS SDK

Tags: javascript, php, forms, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

so I have a checkout page for my website and I have been using the PayPal JS SDK on sandbox mode for a while now to process test payments for products and it works fine it clicks the form submission after payment is captured so I am confident I want to switch to live mode, So I have switched to live mode in the Paypal dashboard and now JS doesn't seem to click the form submission anymore.

Does the live mode client-ID/secret-key need to be the same as the testnet or something like that? or is it fine that I created a new client-ID for live mode?

UPDATE: When I watch the console I can see the form request details for about 1 second, it seems that PayPal refreshes my checkout page and I think that might be preventing my form from submitting fully(?)

I found similar questions but they were really outdated from like 7+ years ago.. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

This is what I have on my checkout page..

```
<!----------- Set up a container element for the button ----------->
            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

            <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
            <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_CLIENT_ID&currency=GBP"></script>

            <script>
                // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
                paypal.Buttons({

                    //****************  SET UP TRANSACTION / CREATE ORDER  ****************//

                    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                        return actions.order.create({
                            purchase_units: [{
                                amount: {
                                    value: '<?php echo number_format($totalprice['totPrice'], 2);?>'
                                }
                            }]
                        });
                    },

                    //************  FINALIZE TRANSACTION - APPROVE CUSTOMER HAS PAID  ************//

                    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

                            // SUCCESSFUL CAPTURE! //

                            //*********************  NOW JS 'CLICKS' SUBMIT BUTTON ON CONFIRMATION FORM  **********************//

                            document.getElementById("cnfrmd").click();

                        });
                    }
                }).render('#paypal-button-container');
            </script>


<form method="POST" action="" id="paypalconf" name="paypalconf">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['sessionID'];?>" name="userID">
              <input type="hidden" value="PayPal" name="paytype">
              <input type="hidden" value="Confirmed" name="confirmation">
              <input type="hidden" value="Preparing.." name="ordprogress">

              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['email'];?>" name="email">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['first_name'];?>" name="first_name">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['last_name'];?>" name="last_name">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['product'];?>" name="product">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['shipping'];?>" name="shipping">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['quantity'];?>" name="quantity">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y" ,strtotime($subdetails['date'])); ?>" name="date">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo number_format($totalprice['totPrice'], 2); ?>" name="price">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['prodimage'];?>" name="prodimage">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['address_line1'];?>" name="address_line1">
              <?php if (empty($subdetails['address_line2'])):?>
                <input type="hidden" value="N/A" name="address_line2">
              <?php endif ?>
              <?php if (!empty($subdetails['address_line2'])):?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['address_line2'];?>" name="address_line2">
              <?php endif ?>
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['city'];?>" name="city">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['county'];?>" name="county">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['zip'];?>" name="zip">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subdetails['country'];?>" name="country">

              <input style="display:none;" type="submit" value="cnfrmd" name="cnfrmd" id="cnfrmd">
            </form>
```

I expected my form to be submitted after the payment is captured but it looks like the form is being canceled out by some PayPal refresh

Answer (score 0):

1. In your current code, the only thing needed to change to live mode is `MY_CLIENT_ID` must be a live client id
2. `actions.order.create(` and `actions.order.capture(` are deprecated functions. See the current [standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) for an example of creating and capturing a PayPal order with a backend integration (using the v2/checkout/orders REST API). The example backend code in that guide uses node.js, but it can of course be implemented in any language/environment including PHP.
3. The code in your question which submits a form after client-side payment approval is a bad design, and will result in situations where payments are captured without your server being notified of a successful transaction. Change your integration to submit the form data as a JSON `body` payload in either the create or capture routes, when you use `fetch` to post to your server for order creation or capture. Any client-side validation logic can exist in those routes as well, most likely in the create route. If you want the buttons to be disabled when the form is not in a valid state, see [validate user input](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/validate-user-input/). This is something you can worry about later once payment processing is working in a robust way (i.e. the backend order creation and capture is more important)